# Javascript/CSS - animation duration in pixel per second

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

How can i set the duration of an transition/animation to pixel per second?

You see the two different wrappers, with a different total height depending on it's colored content. The total speed is the same, given from the css `transition` attribute, thats okay if you want several animations with the same duration. For a smoother look i want to set this transition/animation effect to pixel per second so it takes as long as many pixels there. More content = more pixel = longer animation.

How can i achieve this with vanilla javascript or even css?

```js
var wrapper1 = document.getElementById('wrapper1');
var wrapper2 = document.getElementById('wrapper2');
var header1 = document.getElementById('header1');
var header2 = document.getElementById('header2');
var wrapper1CmputedHeight = wrapper1.scrollHeight;
var wrapper2CmputedHeight = wrapper2.scrollHeight;

header1.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (wrapper1.style.height === '60px') {
    wrapper1.style.height = wrapper1CmputedHeight + 'px';
  } else {
    wrapper1.style.height = '60px';
  }
})

header2.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (wrapper2.style.height === '60px') {
    wrapper2.style.height = wrapper2CmputedHeight + 'px';
  } else {
    wrapper2.style.height = '60px';
  }
})
```

```css
#wrapper1,
#wrapper2 {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height .2s linear
}

#wrapper1 {
  margin-bottom: 40px
}

#header1,
#header2 {
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer
}

#content1 {
  height: 20px;
  background: blue
}

#content2 {
  height: 600px;
  background: green
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper1" style="height: 60px">
  <div id="header1">
    <span>header</span>
  </div>
  <div id="content1"></div>
</div>

<div id="wrapper2" style="height: 60px">
  <div id="header2">
    <span>header</span>
  </div>
  <div id="content2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do this with css transitions, is to dynamically calculate the duration of the transition using a little javascript. So, in your code, I would remove the duration for the transition rule in your css, i,e.

```
#wrapper1,
#wrapper2 {
  background: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height linear
}
```

and I would instead set the duration in the click handler as follows:

```
header1.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if(wrapper1.style.height === '60px') {
    wrapper1.style.height = wrapper1CmputedHeight + 'px';
    wrapper1.style.transitionDuration=(wrapper1CmputedHeight/100)+"s";
  } else {
    wrapper1.style.height = '60px';
  }
})
```

So in this case, I've used a speed of 100px per second (this is the `/100` part in the above code).

Comment: Not that tricky! Clean and simple, great! What do i do if i have different attributes set like "transition: height linear, width .1s linear (allways fixed), opacity .2s linear (fixed too)"? How can i just edit the duration for it's height property?

Comment: In that case you could provide to `transition-duration` a comma separated list of values, one value for each property, e.g.: `wrapper1.style.transitionDuration = '0.3s, 0.1s, 0.1s'` and remove the durations from `transition`. Alternatively, it might be possible to add some additional wrappers and apply the other transitions to those wrappers.

Comment: The solution with several durations is nice, i'll try that! How can i use this calculated duration further in a delay function? In a normal case you just put there the milisecond value, i tried just to put it in like in you're example as "(wrapper1CmputedHeight/100)", but it don't work. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "delay function"? `setTimeout`? If so, multiply it by 1000 to convert it to milliseconds, i.e. `(wrapper1CmputedHeight/100)*1000`.

Comment: Jeah correct, i ment a setTimeout function, i totaly forgot about to recalculate the seconds to milliseconds! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found this [example here](https://codepen.io/branneman/pen/tCdHa) but it seems to do the trick for you (after some tweaking). In this case it implements a quartic interpolation, however you could adjust this algorithm to linear / other if so desired.

```js
//
// Animate
//
var btn1 = document.querySelector('.animate');
btn1.addEventListener('click', function() {
  reset();
  animate();
  btn1.disabled = true;
});

//
// http://easings.net/#easeInOutQuart
//  t: current time
//  b: beginning value
//  c: change in value
//  d: duration
//
function easeInOutQuart(t, b, c, d) {
  if ((t /= d / 2) < 1) return c / 2 * t * t * t * t + b;
  return -c / 2 * ((t -= 2) * t * t * t - 2) + b;
}

function reset() {
  document.querySelector('.square').style.width = Math.floor((Math.random() * 500) + 1) + "px";
}

function animate() {

  var rect = document.querySelector('.square');
  var from = 0;
  var to = window.getComputedStyle(rect, null).getPropertyValue("width").split('px')[0];
  var duration = to * 10;

  var start = new Date().getTime();
  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    var time = new Date().getTime() - start;
    var width = easeInOutQuart(time, from, to - from, duration);
    rect.style.width = width + "px";
    if (time >= duration) {
      clearInterval(timer);
      btn1.disabled = false;
    }
  }, 1000 / 60);
  rect.style.width = from;
}

reset();
```

```css
.square {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>

<button class="animate">Animate</button>
```