# Calculating non-linear CSS transition duration to target a specified initial speed

Tags: javascript, css, math

I have an element in the website that the user drags, upon release of the element I want it to transition to a specific position, I want the initial speed of the transition to match the speed the user was dragging the element at the time they released it.

There is a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47706393/javascript-css-animation-duration-in-pixel-per-second) however it only supports the `linear` timing function, I want to support the other timing functions such as `ease-out`.

I predict this would be solved using a Javascript function that takes an initial movement speed, distance to travel and the timing function as parameters and outputs a duration to assign to the transition.

Comment: Question: If I drag an element and move my cursor in sircualar direction, you do not know/ calculate the speed of transition. How do you expect to determine the speed? Or if I start dragging fast and then after a point, i slow down, how will your transition speed work?

Comment: One hackish way I can think of as of now could be, register a mouse move event and on move, create a list which holds times. Then take the difference between first and last and get the average using length. You can use this average as speed but this is not full proof and will have lot of cases it will fial

Answer (score 0):

Let's think of this as `linear` first to simplify things and then we'll see it works with the other transitions.

So you want the speed of the transition to be the same speed as the user dragging speed. If it was a `linear` transition, then you'd want this speed to just continue until the element gets to where it is supposed to be. So in this case you'd use the speed the user is dragging the element to determine the duration of the linear transition.

Say the user is dragging at `100px/s` and there are `400px` to go, if you set the transition as `400/100 = 4` so `4s linear`, then this would continue moving at the same speed the user left it off at and would get there in a linear fashion.

Now it turns out this is the correct approach for the other transitions as well. If you do an `ease` vs `linear` but both with the same duration and distance, the `ease` will start off going faster then slow down towards the end and they'll arrive at the same time. This is the case for all of them if they have the same duration. So this means all you have to do is take the `distance / user speed` to calculate the duration and set which type of transition you want.

A visual might help, see https://cubic-bezier.com/ as long as the curve starts out above the straight line it'll initially go faster than the linear. And to get the linear going the same speed as the user left it, calculate the duration as `distance/speed`.